# Should events be propagated to records in hasMany relationship?

Tags: ember-data

I have the following relationship between two `DS.Model` classes:

```
App.DocumentType = DS.Model.extend
  ...
  propertyTypeJoins: DS.hasMany("App.DocumentTypePropertyType")

App.DocumentTypePropertyType = DS.Model.extend
  documentType: DS.belongsTo('App.DocumentType')
```

The children records are always embedded and never saved individually:

```
App.Adapter.map 'App.DocumentType'
  propertyTypeJoins:
    embedded: 'always'
```

When I commit a transaction with a `documentType` record and n-related `DocumentTypePropertyType` records, I get the following error:

`"Attempted to handle event 'didCommit' on <App.DocumentTypePropertyType:ember1806:38072> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined"`

Looking into the code I realized that the adapter's `didSaveRecord` method sends a `didCommit` event to each embedded record. This seems perfectly fine since the children are declared to be saved together with the parent (see `embedded: 'always'` above).

The error is raised because the `willCommit` event is not propagated to the children and thus they are still in the `uncommitted` state and can't handle `didCommit` in that state. The parent itself was transitioned to `inFlight` and hence no error is thrown there.

In my opinion, the observed behavior is inconsistent. Either all events should be sent to the children or none. Otherwise all sorts of inconsistent behaviors can arise.

It seems that I'm working against, and not with, ember-data so I stopped to ponder what I'm doing wrong.

Can you tell me?